# Disable Vista UAC for Admin Only

Tags: windows-vista, uac

In vista is there a way to disable the UAC for Administrators only? Preferrably without to much messing with the registry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done via a Group Policy using the Local Policy. [This](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_uac_in_windows_vista.htm) document explain in detail how it can be done and your looking for Method 3 which allows you to disabling prompting for administrators.