# Is it possible to disable UAC for one user only via registry or command line?

Tags: windows, uac

I would like to make a special user that has UAC disabled and I'd like to be able to automate it.

Note that [Disable Vista UAC for Admin Only](https://superuser.com/questions/25423/disable-vista-uac-for-admin-only) is not a duplicate, because it uses GPOs.

Comment: Why are GPOs not a viable solution for you?

Comment: I'm writing an installer and can't set GPOs from it.

Comment: The only special user for which you can disable UAC is Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

UAC is a system-wide setting. It cannot be disabled for JUST one user.

Note: [Disable Vista UAC for Admin Only](https://superuser.com/questions/25423/) also affects ALL admins on the system.