# Windows 8.1 mark an account as a Trusted UAC Account

Tags: windows-8.1, uac, windows-installation, prompt

From what I understand in windows 8 if you want to use/enable UAC you get a prompt unless you hack an icon or use the local SYSTEM account. I am fine with this, however is there a way to make a different Administrative account trusted in the same way SYSTEM is trusted so that it doesn't get the annoying UAC dialog?

In general I have a service account that everything needs to be installed under unless it is a per user install (installed with user rights. It is not practical for tech's to remote in to deploy the application or to deploy with credentials since these utilities that are wrapped with credentials have different distribution channels, company intranet, network push, user self install, AD logon script, etc.

If I disable UAC it appears to break metro applications, so I am not quite sure how to get around this other than creating a trust for a lower level admin account. I am up to suggestions if you have a different approach.

Comment: Why does a service account to run Modern UI applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable UAC for one user only via registry or command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/398793/is-it-possible-to-disable-uac-for-one-user-only-via-registry-or-command-line)